# Syncing (or pre-populating) Firebase data into Angular 5 FormArrays?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

Using Angular 5, AngularFire2, and Firestore, I have a set of items that I want listed out in a grid that will be editable from the grid itself.

In the template, the grid is iterating over a FormArray inside a FormGroup.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Serial Number</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody formArrayName="devices">
        <tr *ngFor="let device of form.controls.devices.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <th scope="row"><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="serialNumber"></th>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="deleteDevice(i)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

In my Angular component, I'm calling buildForm() inside ngOnInit() to initially generate the form to give the template something to work with. If I don't do this, I get errors in the console.

I'm then generating the form again in the collection's snapshotChanges() in order to make sure the data is synced properly between Firebase and the FormArray.

If I don't do this, I'll get weird behavior such as rows remaining in the grid even after the item has been deleted or extra rows appearing once I add in another item.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    devicesCol: any;
    devices: any;

    serialNumber: string;
    form: any;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.buildForm(); // Generate the form initially to give the template something to work with

        this.devicesCol = this.afs.collection('devices', ref => ref.orderBy('deviceName'));
        this.devicesCol.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;            
                const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                return { id, data };
            });
        }).subscribe(result => {

            this.form = this.fb.group({
                devices: this.fb.array([]);
            }); 

            var devicesForm = this.form.get('devices');
            this.devices.forEach((element) => {
                devicesForm.push(this.fb.group({ 'id': element.id, 'serialNumber': element.data.serialNumber, 'deviceName': element.data.deviceName }));
            }
        });

    }

    buildForm() {

        this.form = this.fb.group({
            devices: this.fb.array([]);
        })

    }

    addDevice() {
        this.afs.collection('devices').add({ 'serialNumber': this.serialNumber, 'deviceName': '' });  // Add to firebase
    }

    deleteDevice(id) {
        var devices = this.form.get('devices');
        var deviceID = devices.at(id).get('id').value;
        this.afs.doc('devices/' + deviceID).delete(); // Remove from firebase
        devices.removeAt(id); // Remove from FormArray (probably unnecessary since the form will be rebuilt in snapshotChanges()
    }
}
```

While this does work, I'm not sure it's best way to go about it. Is there a better way to sync data between Firebase and a FormArray?

Comment: i'm having the same issue, the only options I can see are: Use a function: https://gist.github.com/dherges/c8d38817d1e9d97e509eb81ef18894ac#file-nested-form-component-ts-L73 or write the entire object, and hope the fields match: const spacesForm = this.form.get('spaces') as FormArray;
          spaces.forEach((space) => {
            spacesForm.push(this.fb.group(space));
          });